# how to get value from the repeater in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, repeater

i create openforum website . so for that i have  to show different category. i used repeater control but problem is that i want to show specific list of forums in each category.
for this i used 2 repeater.
in 1St repeater just show category name
and in it i used 2nd repeater and in  2nd repeater  i want it shows only that forum list that have that match category id in both forum and category table for that 1st repeater category name?

i want to access category id for 1st repeater category name into 2nd repeater.
plz do help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Some code that you have written would be great.

Comment: Can you please show us your effort, or code which you have tried and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

on the outer repeater,add an ItemDataBound event.

In this event ,use the FindControl to get the inner repeater and DataBind programmatically